# Angular Reactive Form Programmatic Setter

Tags: angular, validation, reactive-programming

I have an [Angular Reactive Form](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms) with validation.
What's the proper way to invoke the setter for my `hiddenComposedField`?

### component.ts

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.myForm = this.formBuilder.group({
    'field1': ['', [Validators.required]],
    'field2': ['', [Validators.required]],
    'hiddenComposedField': [''],
  });

  this.myForm.get('field1').valueChanges.subscribe((val) => {
     this.setHiddenComposedField();
  });
  this.myForm.get('field2').valueChanges.subscribe((val) => {
     this.setHiddenComposedField();
  });
}

setHiddenComposedField() {
    let field1 = this.myForm.get('field1').value;
    let field2 = this.myForm.get('field2').value;

    // This doesn't work, but I want something like it:
    this.myForm.set('hiddenComposedField',field1 + ' ' + field2); // :(
}
```

### component.html

```
<form [formGroup]="myForm">
  <input formControlName="field1">
  <input formControlName="field2">
  <!-- NB: hiddenComposedField is not exposed to the user; -->
  <!--     it is only on the submitted form model. -->
  <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this should work so that you are getting the Control first and then setting its value.

```
this.myForm.get('hiddenComposedField').setValue(field1 + ' ' + field2);
```

Answer (score 0):

Slightly different way using string interpolation

```
setHIddenField(){
 const field1 = this.myForm.get('field1').value;
 const field2 = this.myForm.get('field2').value;
 const separator= ' --- ';
 let result = `${field1} ${separator} ${field2}`;
 this.myForm.get('hiddenComposedField').setValue(result);
}
```

Here is the [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rdzvsi) link.

Answer (score 0):

The ultimate solution for this problem is to subscribe the valueState of the form controls.

```js
import { combineLatest } from 'rxjs';
```

```js
const firstName = new FormControl();
const lastName = new FormControl();
const fullName = new FormControl();

combineLatest([firstName.valueChanges, lastName.valueChanges])
        .subscribe(([firstName, lastName]) => 
                     fullName.setValue(firstName + " " + lastName)
); 

firstName.setValue('Ahmet');
lastName.setValue('Emrebas');
   
console.log(fullName.value); // OUTPUT : Ahmet Emrebas
```

Whenever you change the values in the form, the c field will be updated automatically.

This is the most proper way to solve such a problem.